# How to get Java like PID in scala

Tags: scala

In my Java program, i am using "this.PID" to get the current process PID.

I am looking for something similar in Scala - how to get same 6 char unique PID (as by java prgm).

looked through multiple post. Once such post suggest to use "MemoryManagementFactory".
However this returns @Hostname. Though, I am looking for a way to get similar 6 char JVM format PID.

Please suggest. Scala version: 2.11

Comment: `this.PID` is not valid arbitrary **Java** code AFAIK, you are probably inheriting some class that provides such property or something and your **Scala** code should be able to extend the same class. - Alternatively check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala does not have a special API to get the process id. This is of course limited because of the JVM. Since Scala runs on the JVM, there is no platform independent API that will work no matter what architecture you run your program on. So most of what Scala can provide in this context are wrappers on top of what the Java API offers already in the context of processes.

For example, you could try [scala.sys.process](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/sys/process/index.html) but as the documentation says:

> The underlying basis for the whole package is Java's Process and
> ProcessBuilder classes. While there's no need to use these Java
> classes, they impose boundaries on what is possible. One cannot, for
> instance, retrieve a process id for whatever is executing.

[However, in Windows](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-get-process-id-of-a-java-application/) you can use the `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean.getName` method that will result in a string of the form`[PID]@[MACHINE_NAME]` and you can further process that to get only the PID.

Since JDK 10 you can also directly obtain the PID using `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean.getPid`.

But in both cases you will get the PID of the current running JVM, so if you need the PID of some other running program, I don't think that is possible.

Here is the equivalent Scala code:

```
object Program extends App {

  import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory

  val bean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean
  // Get name representing the running Java virtual machine.
  // It returns something like [PID]@[MACHINE_NAME]. The value before
  // the @ symbol is the PID.
  val jvmName = bean.getName
  System.out.println("Name = " + jvmName)

  // Extract the PID by splitting the string returned by the
  // bean.getName() method.
  var pid = jvmName.split("@")(0).toLong
  System.out.println("PID = " + pid)

  // Since JDK 10 you can get the process ID representing the running Java virtual machine.
  pid = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean.getPid
  System.out.println("PID = " + pid)

}
```

For me it outputs:

```
Name = 12412@VALHALLA
PID = 12412
PID = 12412
```

`VALHALLA` is the name of my host machine, while `12412` is the PID of the current JVM  instance.